# Moving structs of vectors

Tags: c++

I've now spent too much time attempting to getting the following piece of code to not segfault. Can someone explain me why it does so?

I get that the issue lies within some uninitialized memory somewhere.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    vector<int> parents;
};

int main() {
    vector<node> nodedb;
    {
        node df;

        nodedb.push_back(move(df));
    }

    {
        node &existing_node = nodedb[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            node df;
            nodedb.push_back(move(df));

            existing_node.parents.push_back(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you know the total size of the vector in advance, you can call reserve on it, and so long as you don't exceed the vector's capacity, iterators won't be invalidated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `nodedb.push_back` in your loop, this has the potential to invalidate existing pointers / iterators to the vector elements. This happens if the vector needs to grow beyond its current memory allocation - a new chunk of memory is allocated, the vector contents are copied across, and the old memory is freed.

This means that at some point `existing_node` becomes invalid, and after that happens, dereferencing it (via `existing_node.parents.push_back`) causes a crash.

There are a few ways you could fix this:

1. Don't hold a reference to a vector element while you modify the vector - refer to the element directly via its index (i.e. `nodedb[0].parents.push_back`).
2. As suggested by @Neil Kirk above, if the size of the vector is known in advance, calling `vector.reserve` before adding your items means that the vector won't need to reallocate memory as it grows. As well as fixing the immediate problem this will also improve your performance. However holding references to vector items while changing the vector is still not really good practice.
3. As noted by @Greg Hewgill, you could change to using a `list` rather than a `vector`, as lists have the property that existing iterators / references to list elements are not invalidated by changes to the list (unless those elements themselves are erased).

Comment: It might be worth noting that `list<node> nodedb` would not be subject to this problem and the original code would work as intended.